# Using assertRaises unit test for date comparison

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertraises

I'm trying to use `assertRaises(ValueError)` in Python to return an error when the start date of my code is after the end date.

```
class TestDateUtils(unittest.TestCase):
def test_date_range(self):
     start_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
     end_date = datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)
     expected = start_date < end_date
     actual = start_date > end_date

    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        if actual:
            raise ValueError
        else:
            expected
            print("all fine")
```

I'm new to Python (and this is probably nowhere near the correct way to write this).
Would anyone know the correct syntax for trying to produce this end result? I just want to raise a value error if my start date is after the end date.

Comment: The purpose of `assertRaises` is to test that an exception is raised by the code under test in a certain set of circumstances; it is not for raising a value error.

Comment: ok, so what is the best way of achieving the goal of the start date is after the end date using an assert?

Comment: `self.assertLess(end_date, start_date)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `assertRaises` is to test that an exception is raised by the code under test in a certain set of circumstances; it is not for raising a value error.

If you want to assert in a test case that one value is less than another, you can use [`assertLess` or `assertLessEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertLess).

E.g.

```
self.assertLess(end_date, start_date)
```